# Formula() method generate wrong SQL query with fluent nhibernate

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying make specific SQL query on one property. I'm using Formula() method.

```
mapping.Map(o => o.LeadingPeopleText).Formula(@"(SELECT u.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName + ', ' FROM PanelLawyer_LedCases_System_Users ld LEFT JOIN System_Users u ON ld.UserFk = u.Id WHERE ld.CaseFk = Id FOR XML PATH(''))");
```

NHibernate generate this formula like that:

```
(SELECT u.FirstName + '' '' + u.LastName + '','' FROM PanelLawyer_LedCases_System_Users ld LEFT JOIN System_Users u ON ld.UserFk = u.Id WHERE ld.CaseFk = case0_.Id FOR case0_.XML PATH('''')) AS formula0_2_
```

There are two problems:
1. Character single quote is changed on double
2. NHibernate translator doesn't recognize XML command and stick table name to it.

Maybe somebody knows how workaround this problems.

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate parses your query and tries to make it work for subqueries and so on by adding the internally used prefixes. Why it prefixes the FOR XML statement, I don't know, but generally I think this is a very bad idea to do something like this...

Maybe you should try to create a Server Function (not stored procedure) which does run that query for you and you simply call that function within the formula with the id of the object.

For example if I have an entity with a property named Title which is a string, I could also map it to a property TitleUpper which contains the title in upper case

```
Map(p => p.TitleUpper).Formula("(Upper(Title))");
```

Upper is a build in MSSQL function.

Now nHibernate will recognize that Title is a property of my mapped entity and when generating any query it will prefix the Title with the proper table prefix.

```
 select post0_.Id as Id3_, 
   , post0_.Title as Title3_
   , (Upper(post0_.Title)) as formula0_ from Posts post0_
```

Only this way nHibernate can map properties to entities if you even have very complex queries...

Comment: I thought about this solution but unfortunately I couldn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately nHibernate has a bug in understanding `FOR XML PATH`. To fix this, you'll have to create your own `Interceptor` as shown in this example [nHibernate FOR XML PATH bug](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2132?focusedCommentId=23055&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-23055)